# toUpperCase() is not working in react native ,its repeating first letter two times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is my code there are 3 input fields, in uniqueIdNo whenever I have to type it should automatic convert to uppercase. I am using the toUpperCase() function, it converts to the upper case also, but
if I am writing ab two-letter its coming AAB means whatever the first letter I am typing it adding that and coming two times.

```
this.state={
  firstName: props.firstName || '',
  lastName: props.lastName || '',
  uniqueIdNo:props.uniqueIdNo || '',
}
```

```
onChangeText = async (text, identifier) => {
  if (identifier === "FN") {
    this.setState({
      firstName: text
    });
  } else if (identifier === "LN") {
    this.setState({
      lastName: text
    });
  } else if (identifier === "UIN") {
    this.setState({
      uniqueIdNo: text.toUpperCase()
    });
  }
};
```

```
<Item style={{ borderColor: "#00fff", borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
  <Input
    value={firstName}
    keyboardType="default"
    onChangeText={text => this.onChangeText(text, "FN")}
  />
</Item>
<Item style={{ borderColor: "#00fff", borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
  <Input
    value={lastName}
    keyboardType="default"
    onChangeText={text => this.onChangeText(text, "LN")}
  />
</Item>
<Item style={{ borderColor: "#00fff", borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
  <Input
    value={uniqueIdNo}
    onChangeText={text => this.onChangeText(text, "UIN")}
  />
</Item>
```

Comment: Why did you put `async` on your `onChangeText()` function ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the keyboardType property for that in android you can set keyboard type to `visible-password` and iOS `default`.

```
 keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'default' : 'visible-password'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can check my expo-snack link, i couldnt find the error, please do check : [expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/Hymchb0NU)

Code is as below :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TextInput } from 'react-native';
export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props)
this.state={
  firstName:'',
  lastName:  '',
  uniqueIdNo: '',
}
}

onChangeText = async (text, identifier) => {
  if (identifier === "FN") {
    this.setState({
      firstName: text
    });
  } else if (identifier === "LN") {
    this.setState({
      lastName: text
    });
  } else if (identifier === "UIN") {
    this.setState({
      uniqueIdNo: text.toUpperCase()
    });
  }
};

  render() {
    let {firstName,lastName,uniqueIdNo} = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <View style={{ borderColor: "#00fff", borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
  <TextInput
    value={firstName}
    keyboardType="default"
    onChangeText={text => this.onChangeText(text, "FN")}
  />
</View>
<View style={{ borderColor: "#00fff", borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
  <TextInput
    value={lastName}
    keyboardType="default"
    onChangeText={text => this.onChangeText(text, "LN")}
  />
</View>
<View style={{ borderColor: "#00fff", borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
  <TextInput
    value={uniqueIdNo}
    onChangeText={text => this.onChangeText(text, "UIN")}
  />
</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I guess this is the same code what I have written in question, not working

Comment: but have you checked in expo? di you find the error?

Comment: Yes problem is there .. its adding extra stings... I guess toUppercase doesn't work proper in react while typing

Comment: but where? i couldnt find

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (identifier === "UIN") {
var uppercasetext = text.toUpperCase();//To convert Upper Case
this.setState({
  uniqueIdNo: uppercasetext    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property to input called autoCapitalize that can be used for uppercase-issues.

```
   <Input
    autoCapitalize="sentences"
  />
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#autocapitalize